# react native go back to previous stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, navigation, react-navigation

i have problem in this code

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
      return true;
```

all the navigation between Stack A and Stack B is working very well

but when i moving from A to B i can't go back 
i can navigate to screen A but i want to go back

Stack A

```
 const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
                     Login:Login,
                     Home:Home,
                     GulfExpo:GulfExpo,});`
```

Stack B

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Details: {screen: Details,},);


const AppStackNNavigator = createStackNavigator({
        TabNavigator: TabNavigator,}
```

Comment: Do you have some navigator that includes those 2?